# Python "import wx" error

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I recently installed python 2.7.3 (from 2.6), and accidentally reinstalled wxPython 2.8 unicode on my Mac. Now, when I try to import wx, I get

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Why is this? I did `defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes`, and `print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)` still returns `('7fffffffffffffff', True)`. Does this mean it's running in 64-bit mode? If so, is that why I'm getting this error?

EDIT: This also happens when importing wx in python2.6. But nothing should have changed, because I have the same version of wxPython.

Another EDIT: Using `arch`, I've determined that this is happening because it is running in 64-bit mode. However, it is in 64-bit despite `Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes`. Why might this be? I've noticed that /usr/bin/python still runs 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely an architecture mismatch. Instead of running python as 32 bit, try setting this environement variable before compiling wx:

```
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling wx"? I'm on Mac, on which wx only runs in 32-bit because it relies on the Carbon framework, which is outdated and only supports 32-bit. I installed wxPython from a downloaded package.

Comment: Ah I see that now. Still wrong architecture though. Try `arch -i386 python`

Comment: That works, but it doesn't seem like a permanent solution. Is there a way to force Python to open in 32-bit without piping it through another (arch) program? Something like `python -32`?

Comment: If it's not the system python, you should be able to set this in your ~/.profile: `export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run ride(robotframework) in mac,I think that I had the same question to you. you can download the python version(Mac OS X 32-bit i386/PPC installer),yeah ,you must be to use it  instead of others.you can download it from web : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/.this is my case running ride in mac pro